# Casting populated List<BaseClass> to List<ChildClass>

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, inheritance

I have a `List<BaseClass>` with members in it. I would like to cast the list (and all its members specifically) to a type `List<ChildClass>`, where `ChildClass` inherits `BaseClass`. I know I can get the same result through a foreach:

```
List<ChildClass> ChildClassList = new List<ChildClass>();
foreach( var item in BaseClassList )
{
    ChildClassList.Add( item as ChildClass );
}
```

But is there a neater way of doing this? Note - this is done on the WP7 platform.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this if you are really sure all items are castable:

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.Cast<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

Your current code adds `null` if a BaseClass item cannot be cast to ChildClass. If that was really your intention, this would be equivalent:

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.Select(x => x as ChildClass).ToList();
```

But i'd rather suggest this, which includes type checking and will skip items that don't match:

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.OfType<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - in this case I am certain every element is of the specified type. I've split my models up in "dumb" (properties only) and "smart" (all functionality) versions, where the smart classes inherits the dumb.

The first example here worked just like it should - thanks for the help! That goes for you too @Adam Houldsworth

Answer (score 5):

The following is *almost* equivalent to your current code (the only missing thing is it doesn't add nulls for failed casts):

```
var childList = baseList.OfType<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

This will ignore instances where the list contains another derived class other than `ChildClass`.

You can also use:

```
var childList = baseList.Cast<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

But this will throw an `InvalidCastException` on things it cannot cast.