# C#; InvalidCastException, what´s wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I want to cast the Objects of an List to it´s Subclass.
For that I used  [Casting populated List<BaseClass> to List<ChildClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687424/casting-populated-listbaseclass-to-listchildclass)

Now, when I execute the Code I always get an InvalidCastException in System.Core.dll   ""The Object Item cannot be cast to SubItem "

```
[Serializable]
public class SubItem: Item
{
    public SubItem(int id) : base( id)
    {          
    }
}


public getStuff(int id){
 //where the Error is thrown
//Inventory has Items in it, furthermore atm Inventory is definitely not     empty, but could be later on
 var items = Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).Cast<SubItem>().ToList();
}
```

Item is from an API, I am not able to change anything there.
Item inherits from IEquatable.

The LINQ is definitely working, but when I am casting I get the Error. What do i do wrong?

Comment: you have typo `public SubItem(ind id) : base( id)`

Comment: Your inventory contains Items or Subitems?

Comment: `int id` instead of `ind it`. But that should have been a typo, otherwise it wouldn't compile (without a `class ind`..). As I'm guessing, you're trying to cas an `Item` to a `SubItem` which isn't possible. You might want to check if the instance is `typeof(SubItem)`?

Comment: You have objects in the list that have a matching `id` but are not actually a SubItem.  Maybe you need OfType instead, maybe it is a bug.

Comment: Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).ToList<SubItem>()

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your property `Inventory` is strongly typed collection/list/IEnumerable of generic type `Item` (example: `ICollection<Item>`).

The `InvalidCastException` will occur when calling `Cast` if one or more items is not of the type specified in the generic argument. See details in the Microsoft page [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx). To get around that you need to only retrieve items of that type which will execute the cast on them during the filter. This can be done with [Enumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx). Your code then becomes:

```
var items = Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).OfType<SubItem>().ToList();
```

---

From the documentation [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx)

> If an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw an exception. To obtain only those elements that can be cast to type TResult, use the OfType method instead of Cast(IEnumerable).

---

**Edit based on these comments**

Established that all items returned are of type `Item` and not `SubItem`. This explains the exception.

> ... said that the List consists of Item that´s why I want to downcast them to SubItem.

Your inheritance hierarchy as you have posted it in your question is `System.Object` -> `Item` -> `SubItem`. (*I include Object as I am assuming we are dealing with reference types and also everything eventually inherits from System.Object*). What this means is that a `SubItem` could be cast to an `Item` or an `System.Object`, an `Item` instance could be cast to a `System.Object`. However the inverse is not true, you cant cast up the graph. An instance of `System.Object` cannot become an `Item` and an `Item` cannot become a `SubItem`.

Having a generic `List<Item>` is fine, this could contain types `SubItem` or `Item` or anything that derives from `Item`. But again, you cannot cast an instance of `Item` to `SubItem`.

If this is not clear then I recommend you do some reading up on inheritance as well as Polymorphism which is a different topic but also very important if you want to know why inheritance is used and what makes it such a great tool for abstraction.

Comment: I don't believe you need to `.Cast<T>` after doing `.OfType<T>` as it already returns `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I don´t exactly get why I should get an Variable other than Item from the List if the List only contains Item Objects. I added to the Startpost that Item inherits from IEquatable<Item>. If I use your Solution I indeed do not get an Error, but the List is always empty, although if I don´t want to cast it to SubItem I get an List with 11 Elements (which is correct).

Comment: @EsoMoa - I have a feeling that either the returned type is not what you expect or your code is missing an inheritance call somewhere. I would try adding the following line of code to see what the returned types actually are: `var allTypeNames = string.Join(" | ", Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).ToList().Select(x => x.GetType().FullName).Distinct());`

Comment: It returns : dllName.Core.Item

Comment: @EsoMoa - That is the issue. The returned instances in the list are of type `Item` not of type `SubItem` and that is why the `Cast` fails and why the `OfType` filters them out. If you are using `Linq-to-Sql` you will have to provide a discriminator so the correct type is created. If this is a built up list somewhere else then whatever is creating the list needs to create the instances of the correct type.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it´s due to my modest English but I do not get what´s the Problem? I always said that the List consists of >Item< that´s why I want to downcast them to SubItem.

Comment: @EsoMoa - I added an explanation in my answer as the space in the comment is rather limited. I recommend you do some reading on inheritance, casting, and polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some of the items in your list are not of the derived class type, you should be able to see this in the debugger. Also as someone has pointed out you may have to pull the data back from the database before doing the cast, the linq provider may not be capable of doing that for you.

So you could try either of the following:

- Filter out items that are not of SubItem

```cs
var items = Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).OfType<SubItem>().ToList();
```

- Pull the data back from the database before casting

```cs
var items = Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).ToList().Cast<SubItem>().ToList();
```

- Or a combination of the two if the linq provider cannot do the OfType

```cs
var items = Inventory.FindAll(x=> x.id==id).ToList().OfType<SubItem>().ToList();
```

Comment: If I use the first and the last one I don´t get the Error, but my List is empty. If I use the 2nd One I get the same Error.  Why btw, do I have to use ToList() isn´t it already a List?

Comment: @EsoMoa Then I would say that you are not getting back any objects of SubItem. If you hold the results of the FindAll().ToList() and inspect the contents of the list it will show you what the object types are. Then you will know what you can cast them too or fix your ORM tool to map the objects better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Inventory contains a list of "Item" and you want to get a list of "SubItem" replace your line with this:

```
var items = Inventory.Where(x => x.id == id).Select(x => new SubItem(x.id)).ToList();
```

So the first part is going to get you the items that meet your conditions and the second part will create a new SubItem for each one and give you a list of them.