# Convert List<A> to List<B> with Linq c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

How can i convert my list with typ "Person" (created by my database) to typ "myPerson" without getting erros.

I tried this :

```
DataClasses1DataContext d = new 
DataClasses1DataContext(MainWindow.mySqlClass.GetConnection());

var query = from pers in d.Person select pers;

personen = query.ToList();
newPerson = personen.Cast<myPerson>().ToList();
```

But I only get a `System.InvalidCastException`.

```
public partial class myPerson : Person
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Nachname;
    }
    public myPerson(System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Bilder> bilder, string geschlecht, int iD, string nachname, string name)
    {
        Bilder = bilder;
        Geschlecht = geschlecht;
        ID = iD;
        Nachname = nachname;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The Class that Linq created (just the frist rows):

```
public partial class Person : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _ID;

    private string _Nachname;

    private string _Name;

    private string _Geschlecht;

    private EntitySet<Bilder> _Bilder;
```

anyone has a idea how can i convert a List from typ Person to a List with typ myPerson?

or how can i make a "query" that gives can convert from Person to myPerson?

Comment: You need some constructor within `MyPerson` that accepts an instance of `Person` and then use `Select(x => new MyPerson(x))` instead if `Cast<MyPerson>()`.

Comment: How can i do that? 
i am new to c#

Comment: I see you derive `myPerson` (which should be `MyPerson`)  from `Person`. I'd recommend instead using an Interface IPerson that both implement and having a `Person` field in `MyPerson` so you don't copy stuff around unnecessarily. (see "[Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)")

Comment: You will need to have some public properties within `Person` as you can´t access private fields within any other class.

Comment: Using `Mapper` could also we a wise choice

Comment: @Fildor i need to copy the list, cause the first list can be change during run time and at the end i want to comper the first list with the second list which value has changed and which not

Comment: Then just (deep)copy the list. No need for a second class.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Select` ? Cast doesn't map anything automagically, it *casts* the object into another type, ie it allows you to treate the *same* object as if it were another, compatible type. If that's not possible, it throws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every `myPerson` instance can be casted to `Person` because the `myPerson` class inherits from `Person`. But you can't do the opposite, cast a `Person` to `myPerson` so the parent to the child. You could do that only if it was really a `myPerson`, but it is not in this case so the cast fails.

If you have a `Person` and you want to convert it to `myPerson` you should provide a constructor (or factory method) that accepts a `Person` instance and initializes (or returns) the `myPerson` instance.

```
public partial class myPerson : Person
{
    public myPerson(Person p)
    {
        _ID = p.Id;
        _Nachname = p.Nachname;
        _Name = p.Name;
        _Geschlecht = p.Geschlecht;
        _Bilder = p.Bilder;
    }

    private int _ID;
    private string _Nachname;
    private string _Name;
    private string _Geschlecht;
    private EntitySet<Bilder> _Bilder;
    // add properties
}
```

Then you can use:

```
personen = query.ToList();
newPerson = personen.Select(p => new myPerson(p)).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe OP actually only wants to make a deep copy of the list. See comments to the question: _" i need to copy the list, cause the first list can be change during run time and at the end i want to comper the first list with the second list which value has changed and which not"_

Comment: @Fildor: then i dont understand it. Whenever he asks the database for the current `Perons`s he will get a new list with new `Person` instances which he can compare with the old.

Comment: Not sure if *he* is aware of that ... Seems to me a novice coder. Smells like x-y to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from pers in d.Person 
            select new myPerson 
                  {
                     Name = pers.Name,
                     ...
                  } ;
```

Replace the dots (...) with the rest of the properties you want to map.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of entity framework or not, you cannot cast from a collection of classes into a collection of subclasses.

You need to make a new collection, in this case a new List, and fill it with new objects that you make. You could do that with a select in linq like this:

```
d.Person.Select(x => new myPerson(....)).ToList();
```

Which would go through all the Person instances, create a new myPerson for each one, and convert the result to a List.

Don't write the .... though - you need to do this according to your definition of the ctor of myPerson, copying all the fields of Person into myPerson eg:

```
new myPerson(x.Bilder, x.Geschlecht, .......
```

Or as commented, make a ctor for myPerson that takes a Person, then inside the ctor you can copy the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687424/casting-populated-listbaseclass-to-listchildclass) StackOverflow solves your problem ?

Here is the **accepted answer** from Botz3000:
"

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.Cast<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

Your current code adds `null` if a BaseClass item cannot be cast to ChildClass. If that was really your intention, this would be equivalent:

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.Select(x => x as ChildClass).ToList();
```

But i'd rather suggest this, which includes type checking and will skip items that don't match:

```
ChildClassList = BaseClassList.OfType<ChildClass>().ToList();
```

"